# Querying multiple timeseries using Stackdriver/Cloud Monitoring Rest API

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

I am trying to use the Google Cloud monitoring REST APIs to get timeseries data of my project. I have been looking at the documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.timeSeries/list

I do not see any API where I can query for multiple timeseries (with different filters each) using one single REST call. Is that possible with the available APIs ?

For example, for a given timerange, I might want to get the `kubernetes/cpu/usage` metric with certain filters and the `kubernetes/memory/usage` metric with a different set of filters in one single REST API call.

Comment: If you are pertaining to multiple resource on filter, OR can only be used as an operator. (AND will not work) See [Monitoring Filters](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/filters#filter_syntax) to learn more how to utilize these operators.

Comment: instead of timeseries endpoint, try using MQL query https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.timeSeries/query 
, refer to [fetch](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/reference#fetch-tabop) docs for instructions

Comment: When i use the MQL and the query API to get multiple timeseries responses, i end up with a 400 with an error message that says: "Expect query to have 1 result but had 2."

So i'm guessing, we arent allowed to get more than one timeseries as a response at all ?